# Use Regex to put strings in List

Tags: regex, eclipse, notepad++

I want to put strings in a `List`. To do so, I want to add a comma at the end of each of the following strings:

Here are my strings:

Current:

```
"blue"


"black"


"green"


"yellow"


"orange"


"white"
```

I want the final result to be this:

```
"black",


"blue",


"green",


"yellow",


"orange",


"white",
```

How can I accomplish this?

I tried regexes like these:

```
\w*"\b

["]^.*

(.")$
```

Can anyone help please?

EDIT: Using Andreas' solution, I was able to solve this issue using Eclipse and it's search/replace mechanism. The strings were saved in a file in my project.

Thank you

Comment: What has this to do with java?

Comment: Where are you trying to accomplish this? notepad++?

Comment: `replaceAll("(?m)\"[ \t]*$", "\",")`. See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lE8sT8/1).

Comment: thanks @Andreas that was perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Find

```
(?<=")$
```

Replace with

```
,
```

Answer (score 0):

ndn's solution does not work in Eclipse because it does not allow zero-length matches (no match is shown then). A cross-tool solution is matching and capturing the text we need and then using a backreference in the replacement pattern to reinsert this text back. More, one does not need to use `(?m)` multiline modifier as `$` matches the end of *line* in both NPP and Eclipse.

Use

*Find*: `(")$`
*Replace*: `$1,`

More on [*capturing groups*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and [*backreferences*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) can be found at regular-expressions.info.

See the demo screenshot:

[image]